# current values of memory allocation parameters in c

Tags: c, linux, terminal, heap-memory

how can we check current values of memory allocation parameters that we specify in mallopt() in c on terminal ?
I tried it by mallopt(MALLOC_STATS, &ms) as following

```
    #include "stdio.h"
    #include "malloc.h"
    extern struct malloc_stats ms;
    main()
    {
    void * ptr;
    mallopt(MALLOC_STATS, &ms);

    printf("\n An empty Heap of - %d , is'nt it?\n",getpid());
    getchar();
    malloc_stats();
    //mallinfo();
    getchar();

    ptr=malloc(4*1024);
    printf("\n 4k Bytes are requested\n");
    getchar();
    malloc_stats();
    //mallinfo();
    getchar();

    free(ptr);
    printf("no no sorry release it\n");
    getchar();
    malloc_stats();
    //mallinfo();
    getchar();

    }
```

But it shows error

```
mallocstat.c: In function ‘main’:
mallocstat.c:7:10: error: ‘MALLOC_STATS’ undeclared (first use in this function)
mallocstat.c:7:10: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for 
    each function it appears in
mallocstat.c:7:2: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘mallopt’ makes integer from 
    pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
In file included from mallocstat.c:2:0:
/usr/include/malloc.h:143:12: note: expected ‘int’ but argument is of type 
    ‘struct  malloc_stats *’
```

so where is MALLOC_STATS defined ? or if I Am wrong somewhere then how to check current values of memory allocation parameters that we specify in mallopt() in c on terminal ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read the [`mallopt` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mallopt.3.html), there is no such parameter defined.

Comment: Maybe you meant `malloc_statistics_t` instead of `MALLOC_STATS`?

Comment: yes Joachim there is no such parameter defined !! But how to check current values of memory allocation parameters.